# I have a Django Question regarding the command line regarding running python manage.py test

Tags: python, django

I got this error when I was running the command python manage.py test in the absolute pathname
C:\Users\vitorfs\Development\myproject\myproject on the command line which I opened by selecting Run as Admin on Windows.  In boards.py, I have the following

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import TestCase

    class HomeTests(TestCase):
        def test_home_view_status_code(self):
            url = reverse('home')
            response = self.client.get(url)
            self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

This is the errors I'm getting:

`1. Failed to import test module: board.tests.  2. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named django.core.urls`

I am having trouble fixing the error.  I followed the tutorial on Django at https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html

Can you show me what this means and help me fix this error?

Just to let you know, I'm learning Python and Django for fun.

Comment: This is probably due to the tutorial being outdated. For your version of python/django, you should use `from django.urls import reverse`. Also it would be good if you put the error code here instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Okay - so the errors the screenshot are telling me are
1. Failed to import test module: board.tests.
2. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named django.core.urls
Ehsan88

Comment: I fixed the error by changing django.core.urlresolvers import reverse to django.urls import reverse.  It works.  Thanks, Ehsan88.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reinstalling django is only option because your `core` utilities are broken**

Follow These Steps:

In Your Command prompt- **`pip uninstall django`**
In Your Command prompt- **`pip install django==2.7`  # Assuming That You've django 2.7**

Maybe This Would Help, **Let Me Know If There Are Any More Problems** I'am up for you!

Comment: Versions of Django differ.

Comment: Aryan, can you show me how to fix a problem I'm having with Django.